# Why using compact method in Livewire view raised error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

On a Laravel site I pass 2 parameters to Blade file:

```
class CrudAppImages extends Component
{
    ...
    public function render()
    {
        $appImageRowsCount = AppImage
            ::getByTitle($this->filters['title'], $this->filters['extended_search'])
            ->count();

        $backendPerPage = (int)Cache::get("backend_per_page", 20);
        $appImageDataRows = AppImage
            ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->with('creator')
            ->getByTitle($this->filters['title'], $this->filters['extended_search'])
            ->paginate($backendPerPage);

        return view('admin.app-images.crud-app-images', [
            'appImageDataRows' => $appImageDataRows,
            'appImageRowsCount' => $appImageRowsCount
        ])->layout('components.admin');
    }
```

and that work OK. But when I tried to use compact method:

```
return view('admin.app-images.crud-app-images', [
    compact('appImageDataRows', 'appImageRowsCount')
])->layout('components.admin');
```

I got error in Blade page:

```
Undefined variable $appImageRowsCount
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.45.1",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.6",
```

Comment: You are creating an array of `compact(...)`. So instead of returning `view(viewName, [compact(...)])` you should return `view(viewName, compact(...)`. Remove the `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've already commented but will also provide a more in-depth answer.*

---

`compact()` is a PHP array function, in short, it creates an array from user-defined variables and their values. [Documentation can be found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

You are creating an array of the `compact()` array instead of directly passing the `compact()` array to your view.

To solve your issue you should remove the `[]` as follows.

```
return view('admin.app-images.crud-app-images', [
    compact('appImageDataRows', 'appImageRowsCount')
])->layout('components.admin')
```

To

```
return view('admin.app-images.crud-app-images',
    compact('appImageDataRows', 'appImageRowsCount')
)->layout('components.admin')
```

---

**Why does this happen?**

I'm not completely sure how Laravel internally interprets the values a user passes to a view, so I can't give a definitive answer. Below is an assumption.

In your original code, you are effectively passing the following to the view;

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "variable" => "value",
    "variable" => "value",
    "variable" => "value",
  ]
]
```

This means that the variables you've passed are nested in an array, I guess Laravel tries something like `$viewData["your_variable"]`, but since you've passed them wrong it has to do something like `$viewData[0]["your_variable']` which it cannot do.

Keep in mind that this is purely hypothetical, if someone does know the answer I would love to be enlightened.

### **Update**

I've found that passing the variables like so; `[compact(...)]` actually causes Laravel to not even interpret those variables.

Another assumption, I guess Laravel looks at the `__data` array, which obviously gets incorrect values.

Example 1 (wrong);

```
// Controller
return view('a-view', [compact('foo', 'bar')]);

// View:
dd(get_defined_vars());

// Output:
array:5 [
  "__path" => "some_path"
  "__data" => array:3 [
    "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#460 …23}
    "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 …40}
    "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#2039 ▶}
  ]
  "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#460 …23}
  "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 …40}
  "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#2039 ▶}
]
```

Example 2 (right)

```
// Controller
return view('a-view', compact('foo', 'bar'));

// View:
dd(get_defined_vars());

// Output:
array:7 [
  "__path" => "some_path"
  "__data" => array:12 [
    "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#460 …23}
    "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 …40}
    "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#2039 ▶}
    "foo" => array:2 [▶]
    "bar" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
  "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#460 …23}
  "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 …40}
  "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#2039 ▶}
  "foo" => array:2 [▶]
  "bar" => array:2 [▶]
]
```